# How to overload [] operator for mpf_t array in a template class in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, mpfr

I am trying to develop a custom class in *C++* which would contain a `mpfr_t` array.
The problem is, I do not know how to overload the `[]` operator to access array elements.
See the code below:

```cpp
template <const unsigned int N>
class MyClass<mpfr_t, N> {
 private:
    mpfr_t array[N];
 public:
    mpfr_t& operator[] (const unsigned int i) const {
        assert(0 <= i && i < N);
        return array[i];
```

The problem with the code above is that I cannot use `const` and return a reference; as this would allow for potential value modification. What is usually done in such cases is that people write two versions of `[]`: one `const` for constant class instances returning a value (not a reference) and another `non-const` which returns the reference. However, I cannot return `mpfr_t` type - this is simply not allowed by the library design:

```
error: function cannot return array type 'mpfr_t' (aka '__mpfr_struct [1]')
```

I realise that the problem stems from wrapping a *C*-dedicated code into strictly *C++* mechanism of operator overloading, but I wonder if there is any hack around it?

Comment: How about returning a `mpfr_t const &` (a const ref) for the `const` version ? It's quite common.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] with all required header files and fixed syntax errors due to missing closing braces? The shown code snippet doesn't return mpfr_t, the error is unrelated.

Comment: @wohlstad : that did it! Do you mind converting your comment to a full answer so that I accept it?

Comment: You need two overloads of `operator[]` one `const` and other none const.

Comment: @maciek added an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `const` version of `operator[]` by returning a const reference, instead of a non-const one (as you do in the current version):

```
//-----vvvvvvv-----------------------------------vvvvv--
mpfr_t const & operator[] (const unsigned int i) const {
    assert(0 <= i && i < N);
    return array[i];
}
```

Note that you can still have the non-const overload as well:

```
mpfr_t & operator[] (const unsigned int i) {
// ...
```

The first overload will be chosen if your `MyClass` object is `const`.